# Simplify Task foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach, task

I have a number of foreach loops where I am adding items to a list of Tasks to await on before continuing.

I have the following layout for each, however I feel this is fairly verbose so wanted to see if there was a more succinct way to write this?

I need to catch any errors for each DoTaskOnItem and log this and continue with any other tasks still remaining.

```
    private async Task DoListOfTasks(List<string> items)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await DoTaskOnItem(item);
                }
                catch
                {
                    AddErrorMessage($"Error: {item}");
                }
            });

            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

Comment: Well, what do you plan on doing with the errors?  You should wrap your outer await in a try-catch block and then do what you want to do with the errors in the catch block.  They will be all wrapped inside an AggregateException.  Also relevant: is this running in a UI?  Library code?  You should really be thinking about the continuation of your awaits, i.e. whether you want them to continue on the captured context or on the pool.

Comment: I am not sure how you consider that verbose, there are only about 15 lines.

Comment: ^ yes, and I agree with @AndyG.  That's not verbose at all.

Comment: Microsoft's Reactive Framework makes it quite nice: `private async Task DoListOfTasks(List<string> items) => await from item in items.ToObservable() from x in Observable.FromAsync(() => DoTaskOnItem(item)) select x;`. Just need to introduce some error handling.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the feedback - I just seem to be repeating this in a few places - wanted to make sure there was not a better way to write it.  Thanks @Enigmativity i'll take a look at that.

Comment: Why the Task.Run? Is DoTaskOnItem I/O-bound, CPU-bound or both? If it's purely I/O without time-consuming calculations you don't need Task.Run. If it's CPU-bound, i.e. uses time-consuming calculations or in general takes some time, but is already async via Task.Run you don't need an outer Task.Run either. So you could just do `await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(task => task.ContinueWith(t => AddErrorMessage($"Error: {item}: {t.Exception}"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
private Task DoListOfTasks(List<string> items)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(items.Select(item => Task.Run<Task>(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            await DoTaskOnItem(item);
        }
        catch
        {
            AddErrorMessage($"Error: {item}");
        }
    })));
}
```

I'd move exception handling inside `DoTaskOnItem`, it would simplify to:

```
private Task DoListOfTasks(List<string> items)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(items.Select(DoTaskOnItem));
}
```

And at this point the method `DoListOfTasks` would not even be necessary as it's too simple.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was after thank you, I really like the bottom one, however I have some extra parameters generally, which I pass into the DoListOfTasks method, can I pass them in as well?

Comment: @user3284707 if you have extra parameters: `Task.WhenAll(items.Select(item => DoTaskOnItem(item, param2, param3)));` - not as nice, but still pretty clean.

Comment: @user3284707 no problem. Glad it helped :)